# Spring MVC 3 : Ambiguous mapping found

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I am playing with spring MVC 3.1 and testing different features. I wanted to verify following statement taken from [@RequestMapping#value doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value%28%29)

```
If you have a single default method (without explicit path mapping), then all requests without a more specific mapped method found will be dispatched to it. If you have multiple such default methods, then the method name will be taken into account for choosing between them
```

So I created following controller with multiple default handler methods.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping
    public @ResponseBody String greet() {
        return "Hi Book!";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public @ResponseBody String meet() {
        return "Nice to meet you Book!";
    }
}
```

Here is web application context configuration

```
<beans ....>
<!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.botreeconsulting.lms.web"/>

  <!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

But it seems I messed up something as it is giving me following error at the time of deployment:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'bookController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.botreeconsulting.lms.web.BookController.meet()
to {[/book],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'bookController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.botreeconsulting.lms.web.BookController.greet() mapped.
```

Now the question is does this controller models what is written in the document? I feel that I didn't get it properly. Please guide me to model the controller to match the statement about multiple default handlers.

Thanks, Amit

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a controller as given below, all requests other than `/book/edit` will be directed to `mydefault()` while `/book/edit` will be sent to `meet()`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping
    public @ResponseBody String mydefault() {
        return "Hi Book!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit")
    public @ResponseBody String meet() {
        return "Nice to meet you Book!";
    }
}
```

In your sample you have two methods without explicit path mapping.

Comment: `mydefault()` will handle /book only not /book/abc.

Comment: Arun, `If you have multiple such default methods...`. Is it possible to configure multiple default methods?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple defaults? In any design there will be only one default

Comment: Arun, I understand that there is only single default possible in a controler. Now how come this Spring document comment says `If you have a single default method (without explicit path mapping), then all requests without a more specific mapped method found will be dispatched to it. If you have multiple such default methods, then the method name will be taken into account for choosing between them`?

Comment: I think what it means is if you have more than 1 method without the url mapping(ie with only `@RequestMappin` no path speficied` then the name of the method will be considered. Assume that to the above example you add a method named `add` with annotation `@RequestMapping` and then you request `/book/add` then the `add` method will be called.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I wanted to check ahd hence I created the example with multiple methods with @ReqeustMapping(without explicit path) and ended with ambiguity error. All I wanted is to validate that it is not possible to have multiple default request mapping methods even though it is stated in the document.

Comment: Can you share your spring mvc configuration? Are you using an `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` or `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`

Comment: You can have a look at the answer provided by Rossen Stoyanchev also.

Comment: I haven't specified `HandlerMapping` explicitly so it would be `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` as Rossen Stoyanchev posted. For reference I have  added mvc configuration in original post

Answer (score 5):

Arun, your answer is correct with the caveat that in Spring 3.1 it depends which HandlerMapping-HandlerAdapter pair is configured.

The described behavior is supported with the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping & AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter which have been in use since Spring 2.5 and are still enabled by default when no other HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter beans are defined.

The RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter added in Spring 3.1 (see Spring 3.1 reference docs) as a replacement for the former do not support the same behavior -- i.e. falling back on the method name in case of ambiguous mappings as well as having a default method (when no explicit mappings are defined). The new HandlerMapping-HandlerAdapter pair is enabled by default from the MVC namespace and from MVC Java config and is recommended for use going forward.

The Java doc referenced by Arun needs an update. I've created a ticket for that [SPR-9042](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9042).

Comment: Hi, Rossen. Can you please clarify a bit the statement `enabled by default from the MVC namespace` - do you mean `<mvc:annotation-config>` tag, or the tag registers just another pair of HandlerMapping/HandlerAdapter?

Comment: Also, can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671776/spring-mvc-why-this-hello-world-run-well-without-annotation-driven-tag-unlike-a - in this question the controller is annotated only with '@Controller' while its single method is annotated '@RequestMapping("/hello")' am I understanding correctly that this configuration will work only in pre 3.1 versions(without `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag) because of the changes in Spring 3.1?