# Ambiguous mapping found with ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-4

How to map requests to methods without explicit annotations on top of methods? For instance, the following request:

```
http://somedomain:8080/SampleSpring/access/loginFailed
```

should be mapped to

"loginFailed" method of "AccessController" without the need of explicit annotation on method like:

```
@RequestMapping("/access/loginFailed")
```

Here is my spring configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.robikcodes.samplespring"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.robikcodes.samplespring.controller"/>
        <property name="caseSensitive" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
        </property>
</bean>   

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class AccessController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void login(ModelMap m) {}

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginFailed(ModelMap m) {
        m.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "access/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap m) {
        m.addAttribute("logoutStatus","true");
        return "access/login";
    }
}
```

I got the following error (seems like only login method was mapped properly):

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'accessController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.robikcodes.samplespring.controller.AccessController.logout(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
to {[],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'accessController' bean method
public void com.robikcodes.samplespring.controller.AccessController.login(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) mapped.
```

Comment: Although a different question, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8909851/248082) also applies to your question.

Comment: Yeah it does. I do not know how to use DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping & AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter instead of RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter. Even if I do replace then still they are deprecated. Does this mean there is no way to use method names without using deprecated classes?

Comment: In fact [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) is not deprecated and you should use it and it also supports full method signatures.

Comment: I meant DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter  are deprecated. In the link you pointed, Rossen says: "The new HandlerMapping-HandlerAdapter pair is enabled by default". Then why is my code not working? Do I need to declare RequestMappingHandlerAdapter explicitly? If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [`ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html) with an assumption that is not correct; from Java doc:

> Implementation of HandlerMapping that follows a simple convention for
>   generating URL path mappings from the class names of registered
>   Controller beans as well as @Controller annotated beans.

The documentation does not say that it also follows *method names*. The main reference of comparing "handler mappings" for your controller is the `@RequestMapping` annotations put on your methods. So, with your controller Spring reads them as:

```
{methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}
```

for **all** the defined methods in `AccessController` that has the following `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

That's why you see the ambiguous exception.

To my understanding, the cleanest solution is to use `value` attribute of `@RequestMapping` to define different request URIs. It's not really recommended to go for a solution that tries to map request URIs to method names.